# Android stop FragmentTransaction animation

Tags: android, animation, fragment

Any idea on how I can stop the fade animation when invoking replace as below?

```
    FragmentManager     fm          = activity.getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(Id,Fragment,Tag);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simple:

```
 transaction.setCustomAnimations(0,0);
```

You can also use this method to set any custom animation you want, by passing a reference to `R.anim.` resource.

Comment: Yip, this is the correct answer. However it did not help me because the ListView in the app I'm working on is being animated via another activity which overlays the ListView. Pretty hectic stuff hey...but I found a workaround...

Comment: For some reason, certain device has default fade animation even if you set custom animation. Any Fix ?

Comment: How is it possible when we Override the OnAnimationCreate method?