# How to remove animation of fragment moving to toolbar

Tags: android, animation, kotlin, fragment, toolbar

My problem is the unnecessary animation of moving the fragment to the toolbar. The toolbar lies in the activity to which our fragments belong.

If in more detail, then: we have two fragments A and B, we move from fragment A to fragment B, and fragment B has a toolbar 2 times higher than fragment A.
It's okay for now.

Problems begin when returning from fragment B to fragment A: fragment A has a toolbar 2 times less in height than fragment B, with when passing to fragment A, the content of fragment A begins to move animated to the reduced toolbar.

I do not need this, do not need to see the animation of the movement.
How to remove it or do you move the fragment to the toolbar for 1 frame?

Comment: Use transaction.setCustomAnimations(0,0); see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14237963/5658915

Comment: Thanks for answer, but the result is the same, its not worked